# Inject variables directly to a function passed on from React-Apollo <Mutation /> component and not as props

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

So I have a apollo  component that I wanna send variables to from event.target and so on, it's for a table with different cells I wanna be able to determine what cell is clicked. I found another stack owerflow post where they did something like this, where u inject the variables when you run the function rather then props to the apollo  component.

but I can't get it work, am I missing something here or do I need to structure differently?

This is a much bigger  but I have striped the example of alot of things that are not needed for the example.

```
    import { **CREATE_BOOKING**, } from "../queries";

    const selectBooking = (e, **createBooking**) => {

      **createBooking**({
        varibles: {
          $data: {
            payed: false,
            notified: false,
            activity: props.activity,
            activityId: props.id,
            time: moment(e.target.getAttribute("time")),
            cost,
            selected: true,
            durationMin
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };

    return (
          <Mutation mutation={**CREATE_BOOKING**} variables={I don't want to enter the variables here}>
            {(**createBooking**, { data }) => (
              <div className="WeekCalender">

                        {rows.map(row => {
                          return (
                            <tr key={row}>
                              <td className="WeekCalender__Cell">{row}</td>
                              <td
                                onClick={e => selectBooking(e, **createBooking**)}
                                time={getCurrentTime(0, row)}
                                className={checkIfBooked(
                                  0,
                                  row,
                                  props.activity.name,
                                  allBookings,
                                  props.currentBookings
                                )}
                              />
                            </tr>
                          );
                        })}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </React.Fragment>
                )}
              </div>
            )}
          </Mutation>
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { CREATE_BOOKING, } from "../queries";

    const selectBooking = async (e, createBooking) => {

      await createBooking({
        varibles: {
          data: {
            payed: false,
            notified: false,
            activity: props.activity,
            activityId: props.id,
            time: moment(e.target.getAttribute("time")),
            cost,
            selected: true,
            durationMin
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };

    return (
          <Mutation mutation={CREATE_BOOKING}>
            {(createBooking, { data }) => (
              <div className="WeekCalender">

                        {rows.map(row => {
                          return (
                            <tr key={row}>
                              <td className="WeekCalender__Cell">{row}</td>
                              <td
                                onClick={e => selectBooking(e,createBooking)}
                                time={getCurrentTime(0, row)}
                                className={checkIfBooked(
                                  0,
                                  row,
                                  props.activity.name,
                                  allBookings,
                                  props.currentBookings
                                )}
                              />
                            </tr>
                          );
                        })}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </React.Fragment>
                )}
              </div>
            )}
          </Mutation>
        );
```